# JQuery set timer for event triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is any way to set the slider bar plays automatically like for example, when I click the play button, the slider bar and the value will increase automatically. Here is my slider bar: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/6/)

Basically what I wanted is I clicked on the play button, then the slider bar and its value will increase automatically and stops for few seconds at each value before increment.

Through my research, I know there is a method called `setInterval()` will repeat certain event automatically but I not sure how to implement it.

And this is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/7/) after I added the auto play function but my slider bar is not coming out.

Comment: Hi, haven't seen the solution yet but your second fiddle has errors. Line# 35: replace with `$('#btnPlay').on('click',function(){`, (here you did not called btnPlay correctly as it requires # for calling by id) then the line ends with a `.` that is not required. Then you are trying to set values `setValue` with a `:` in between while it should be `,` (a comma). This will make your slider show.

Comment: @Cyberpks Would you mind to provide me the answer in jsfiddle?

Comment: See here, http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/11/ . I have corrected the second fiddle. I am not sure but does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED ANSWER]**

Here is your final solution (I hope), [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/13/)

Basically you were using `step` method for incrementing the time, but `step` is called when slider is moved by mouse. You should use the `change` method to update the time value.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({       
    min: 0,
    max: 1380,
    step: stepOne,
    animate: "slow",
    change: function(e,ui)
    {
        var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
        var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

        if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
        if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;
        if(minutes==0)minutes = '00';

        // Convert 24 hours format into 12
        if(hours == 0){
            hours = 12;
            ext = "AM";
        }
        if(hours == 12){
            ext = "PM";
        }
        if(hours > 12){
            hours = hours - 12;
            ext = 'PM';
        }

        $('#sliderValue').html(hours+':'+minutes + ext);
    }
});
```

Comment: But then let's say I wanted to pause it after I clicked the play. Am I able to pause it?

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/14/ you can just check a boolean value for it.

Comment: I see. So you are doing like if it's not paused, then you execute the loop. If it is paused, it will go out the loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/10/

```
$('#btnPlay').on('click', function(){
    // call a recursive function here...
});
```

You can change your logic inside the function.  But normally I use a front-end framework such as Ember or Angular that helps you achieve what you want to do easily.

Comment: Can you help me take a look at the second fiddle? I've added the codes and its causing the slider bar not appearing

Comment: setValue(0:00) will cause the error. I think javascript don't understand 0:00 (it's not a string nor a number)

Comment: So do you have any ideas how to fix that based on that jsfiddle?

Comment: my guess is in your fiddle you set max: 1380, so I just calculate the value for each time and setTimeout those values to move the bar.

Comment: oops. I just realized I did not save the fiddle for you.. one sec

Comment: Sorry but your updated fiddle has no method for the auto play as well :(

Comment: I think if you click play it will play.  I bound the function to the div 'click' event